# Add something to $PATH before Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have 2 versions of the same package (1 installed via brew, and the other one built locally in a bin folder). Currently my $PATH looks like this:

`/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/user/Projects/package-i-need/bin:`

As you can see, the brew path comes first, so when I type `package-i-need` on my terminal I get the brew version. I am trying to instead change it to the locally built version but I am unable to add this path BEFORE the brew path.

I have tried the following on my .zprofile:
`export PATH="/Users/user/Projects/package-i-need/bin:$PATH"` but no luck.

In case it matters, I am using an M1 Mac.

Comment: Did you log out and in again for it to take effect? Are you actually using `zsh`? What happens if you run `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: is a login/out required before checking with `echo $PATH`? I only opened a fresh terminal window each time I made changes. Yes I am using `zsh`